# Swift create Date with components

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone

I have a problem with the creation of dates and the timezone of the device which causes problems in my unit tests.

Here my code to create a date:

```
private func createDate(weekday: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int)->Date{

        var components = DateComponents()

        components.hour = hour
        components.minute = minute
        components.year = 2016
        components.weekday = weekday
        components.weekdayOrdinal = 10
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")

        var cal = Calendar.current
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")!

        return cal.date(from: components)!
    }
```

Here my test where I create a date on a Monday 0:01 in TimeZone Paris:

```
    func testMon0001(){

            let date = createDate(weekday: 2, hour: 00, minute: 01)

 let unitFlags : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.era, .hour, .minute, .day, .month, .year, .timeZone, .weekday]
        var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: date)
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")

        guard let hour = components.hour else {
            [...]
        }

[...]

        }
```

In the end hour is 16 if the device is running on timezone Vancouver which is not correct. The date object is  "2016-03-06 23:01:00 +0000"

What do I have to do to ignore the devices timezone?

Comment: How did you got `"2016-03-06 23:01:00 +0000"` string? By printing out `Date` object? Like `print(date)`?

Comment: Yes. It is the console output.

Comment: Printout of `Date` object always shows date in UTC/GMT/Zulu timezone, which has 1 hour difference with `Central European Time`. `"2016-03-06 23:01:00 +0000"` is midnight + 1 minute of the next day in CET. So **it is** correct.

Comment: Also, when it becomes 16? When you convert it to string using `DateFormatter`? Did you specified timezone there too?

Comment: components.hour is 16. Will try it with DateFormatter

Comment: Here my DateFormatter printed date: 2016-03-07T00:01:00 +0100. So the date object seems to be correct